# how to get caller of function within a function in lua?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

how can one get the caller of function within a function in lua?

Specifically I'm looking (for debug purposes in the command output, e.g. print) the ability to log when a common function is called, with an indication of where it was called from.

This could be just the filename of where it was called from for example

i.e.

```
File 1 - Has commonly used function 

File 2 - Calls of the the file one functions
```

PS Mud - I actually get a nil when doing this - is this normal then?  No way to get more info in this case:

Called file;

```
SceneBase = {}
  function SceneBase:new(options)
  end
return SceneBase
```

Calling file:

```
require("views.scenes.scene_base")
local scene = SceneBase.new()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`debug.getinfo(2).name` will give you the name of the calling function if it has one and it is a string. If it's an anonymous function, you'll get `nil`, if it's stored in a table using something other than a string key, you'll get `?`.

```
function foo() print(debug.getinfo(2).name) end

-- _G["foo"] => function name is a string
function bar() foo() end
bar() --> 'bar'

-- _G[123] => function name is a number
_G[123] = function() foo() end
_G[123]() --> '?'

-- function has no name
(function() foo() end)()  --> 'nil'
```

Comment: thanks - I'm getting a "nil" in the case I have - I put as a PS in my original post - no way to get more info here?

Comment: `name` gives you the calling *function* name. In your example, there is no name (the calling function is a compiled Lua file, and the chunk isn't assigned to anything with a name). If you want to the name of the calling *file*, then you can use `source` or `short_src` instead of `name`.

Answer (score 0):

The Lua [debug library](http://www.lua.org/pil/23.1.html) lets you get the stack trace.

Comment: I see that with "print ("Info: ", debug.getinfo(1).short_src)" I can get info on the current function.  But replacing the getinfo parameter with a 2 to get details of the function that called it didn't seem to work. Am I on the right track here?